# How to send comma separated taxonomy term (as link to taxonomy term url ) from preprocess to twig file as single variable?

Tags: 8, theming, uri

According to my requirements I have to use views preprocess and views-view.html.twig

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view(array &$variables) {


  $aliasManager = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager');

    if (isset($variables['rows'][0]['#rows'])) {
      $nodeValues = [];
      foreach ($variables['rows'][0]['#rows'] as $value) {

        $nodeValue['created'] = $value['#row']->_entity->created->value;
        $nodeValue['external_url'] = $value['#row']->_entity->field_url->uri;
        $nodeValue['title'] = $title = $value['#row']->_entity->title->value;
        $nodeValue['nid'] = $title = $value['#row']->_entity->nid->value;
        $nodeValue['tid'] = $value['#row']->_entity->field_topic->entity->tid->value;

        // section referenced to node
        $nodeValue['section'] = $value['#row']->_entity->field_topic->entity->name->value;

        $topics = "";
        foreach($value['#row']->_entity->field_topic2 as $val){
          $topics != "" && $topics .= ", ";
          $topics .= $val->entity->name->value;
        }

        $nodeValue['topics'] = $topics;

        $nodeValues[] = $nodeValue;


      }

      $variables['node_values'] = $nodeValues;
    }

 }
```

In twig file :

```
{% for value in node_values %}
        <div class="link_full">
            <div class="title"><a href="{{ value.external_url }}"> {{ value.title }} </a>
            </div>
            {% if logged_in %}
                {% if 'premium' in user.getroles %}
                    <div class="link_details">
                        <div class="timestamp"><a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': value.nid}) }}">{{ value.created|date(format='y-m-d H:i') }}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="topics">{{ value.topics }}</div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Out put is like below :

[image]

Everything is working fine but I need to create Links of terms in above screenshot. And in code its TOPICS in preprocess function.

I have tried various ways to create it as link but that does not work as it just print a tags as html but not links. Please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this like below :

It was always considered as string so I have to send topics in from of array like below:

```
$topics = array();
foreach($value['#row']->_entity->field_topic2 as $val){
  $topics[$val->entity->tid->value]= $val->entity->name->value;
}
```

And then in Twig I made links from them and it worked.

```
<div class="topics">
    {% for key,item in value.topics %}
        <a href="{{ path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': key}) }}">{{item}}</a>
        {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %} # for adding commas after each term
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```